# Map to method c++

Tags: c++

I'm using C++.
I'm tried to make a map to class methods.
I.e:

```
map<int,void*> mapIdToMethod;
```

Method:

```
void MyClass::MyMethod(void*);
```

What i'm tried:

```
mapIdToMethod.insert(make_pair(1, (void*)&MyClass::MyMethod));//Not compiled
 mapIdToMethod.insert(make_pair(1, (void*)&MyClass::MyMethod()));//Not compiled
```

So, What is the best why to do that and how?
Thanks!

*I cannot using `Boost`

Comment: Why use `void*`, not member function pointer?

Comment: @songyuanyao, what i need to replace instead of void*?

Comment: `map::insert` doesn't take two parameters. Use `make_pair`

Comment: @Evyatar: Copying approved answer to your question is useless.

Comment: `I'm using C++`. No you aren't. You are using C language with C++ compiler. See [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

Comment: @Drop I don't think `map` and member function pointer is not c++. You might mean it's not c++11.

Comment: @Drop, how can i change the implementation to work with c++11 style?

Comment: @songyuanyao In C++ you usually want to avoid naked pointers, including function pointers, unless you know what you are doing. "C++ way" is to use functors and templates (as it's done in the standard library). Using `std::map` does not automatically upgrade code to C++.

Comment: @Evyatar I gave you a link with an extensive description and examples of the standard facility called `std::function`. Check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `void*`, just use the member function pointer directly.

```
std::map<int, void (MyClass::*)(void*)> mapIdToMethod;
```

BTW: Your usage of [`std::map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) is wrong. You could

```
mapIdToMethod.insert({1, &MyClass::MyMethod});
```

or use [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)

```
mapIdToMethod.insert(std::make_pair(2, &MyClass::MyMethod));
```

**EDIT**

Note you need an instance to call it, such as:

```
MyClass mc;
(mc.*mapIdToMethod.at(1))(nullptr);
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/TJEKJ48066)

Comment: Thanks! and how can i call to the method? i'm tried mapIdToMethod.at(1)(NULL) and i got syntax error

Comment: You need a instance to call it. See my updated answer. @Evyatar

Comment: can you give me please also answer with c++11 style? (with function(void(void*)) Thanks!

Comment: @Evyatar Better to try it firstly, then ask a new question if you encounter some special issues. Reference: [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for a member pointer is not `void*`. Try the following:

```
#include <map>

class MyClass
{
    void MyMethod(void*);
};

std::map<int, void (MyClass::*)(void*)> maps;
```

and change accordingly the member function's signature.

and for more documentation, please read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: Thanks! and how can i call to the method? i'm tried mapIdToMethod.at(1)(NULL) and i got syntax error